# C# free audio libraries for download

Tags: c#

Are there some free audio libraries for commericial use (like NAudio) that is able to play mp3 (but not NAudio!)
thanks very much! :)

Comment: May I ask why not NAudio? I mean, are there any special features that you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in WMPLib - see this MSDN article on [Creating the Windows Media Player Control Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

At the most basic level you'll need code like this:

```
private void PlayFile(String url)
{
    Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    Player.URL = url;
    Player.controls.play();
}
```

However, you also get events to tell you that the play state has changed so you can start playing a new track, or close the form (for example):

```
Player.PlayStateChange += 
    new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange)

private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

It does mean that your application is tied to Windows - so you can't use Mono.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using DirectSound. The entries for DirectSound are removed from the "Add Reference" dialog in VS 2008 or higher (I think) but you can still browse in the GAC for the proper DLLs. Look for the latest version. It's pretty easy, something like:

```
Device dev = new Device();
dev.SetCooperativeLevel(this.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Priority); // this refers to the form to which DirectSound is tied
SecondaryBuffer sound = new SecondaryBuffer("path\\to\\file", dev);
sound.Volume = /* volume */;
sound.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
```

Comment: DirectSound can't play mp3s - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/gametechnologiesdirectx101/thread/b38936aa-da3a-4deb-8cf2-a890e89ac674

Comment: @ChrisF: Oookay... but it worked when I did it (I still have the game I built like that) so I don't know what that means, and every book I've read says it can.

Comment: Odd - when I was researching this for my own app I was wary of using WMPlib to start off with and everything I found said that DirectSound couldn't play mp3s. So my previous comment may not be 100% accurate ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: Yeah, I found WMPLib incredibly annoying to use, so I looked around and just tried to play the MP3... and it worked! Strange, I know.